# Dissplay result sqlite query in textview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I tried to calculate a report and displays the result in the texview "edt1". But it's not displayed.

there is mydatabasehelper :

```
public void calculrapport(Argent a)
{
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String query = "select sum(Entree) from Argent where date between \"datedebut\" and \"datefin\" ;";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null) ;
    int count = cursor.getCount();

        }
```

There is my class Rapport.java :

```
public void onOKClick ( View v ) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.okrapport) {

        EditText datedebut = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datedebut);
        EditText datefin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.datefin);

        String strdatedebut = datedebut.getText().toString();
        String strdatefin = datefin.getText().toString();

        Argent a = new Argent();
        helper.calculrapport(a);
      edt1.setText( );

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the query works as expected (*especially considering that variables used have the appropriate scope, which would appear unlikely perhaps try using `select sum(Entree) from Argent` to test without the complications of wheteher or not the datedebut and datefin variables can resolve and if so resolve to usable values*) then you need to :-

Extract the appropriate value and return the value from the method and then use the returned value to set the text in the TextView.

To return the value the method should not be void, but have an appropriate return type (String will be used for the example),

- so instead of `public void calculrapport(Argent a)`, use `public String calculrapport(Argent a)` (thus the method will be required to return a string)
- To extract the value the cursor needs to be moved to the appropriate row *(there should only be the one row as the sum function is an aggregate function and there is only the one group (aggregate functions work on gropus) i.e. all rows)*

As such the method could be :-

```
public String calculrapport(Argent a)
{
    String rv = "0"; //<<<< used to return 0 if no rows are selected by the query
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "select sum(Entree) from Argent where date between \"datedebut\" and \"datefin\" ;";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query , null) ;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = cursor.getString(0); //<<<< get the value from the 1st (only) column
    }
    cursor.close(); //<<<< Cursors should always be closed when done with
    return rv;
}
```

To set the TextView with the returned value instead of using :-

```
helper.calculrapport(a);
edt1.setText( );
```

Use :-

```
edt1.setText(helper.calculrapport(a));
```

Or :-

```
String sum = helper.calculrapport(a);
edt1.setText(sum);
```

#### Additional re comment:-

> The problem is located in the SQlite query (select sum(Entree) from
>   Argent where date between \"datedebut\" and \"datefin\" ;) exactly
>   when we call "datedebut" and "datefin" taht located in the class
>   rapport.java

Then `String query = "select sum(Entree) from Argent where date between \"datedebut\" and \"datefin\" ;";`

resolves to :-

```
select sum(Entree) from Argent where date between "datedebut" and "datefin" ;
```

I believe, assuming that datedebut and datefin are string variables, and that they are in a valid SQLite date format e.g. they could be 2018-01-01 and 2018-02-01 (and that values in the date column are formatted as a valid SQLite date format) that you should instead be using :-

```
String query = "select sum(Entree) from Argent where date between '" + datedebut + "' and '" + datefin +"' ;";
```

Which would then resolve to something like :-

**`SELECT sum(entree) FROM argent WHERE date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-02-01';`**

For valid SQLite date formats;  refer to [Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

- *Note the above is in-principle code and has not been tested so may contain some simple typing errors.*

Comment: thanks . I used your advice but it does not give me any result and at the same time the logcat does not displayed any error. Is there any other way please ?

Comment: Really the correct way is for you to learn how to debug code. e.g. why not, at first just use `edt1.setText("this is some text for testing" );`. Does that set the text? if so then you split the problem/issue into being with the `calculrapport` method, otherwise there is a problem with setting the EditText. You could do far worse than look at [Debug your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The problem is located in the SQlite query  (select sum(Entree) from Argent where date between \"datedebut\" and \"datefin\" ;) exactly when we call "datedebut" and "datefin" taht located in the class rapport.java.